# Haproxy configuration

Tags: haproxy

can anyone explain more in depth about HAproxy health check configuration. I don't really understand this part

```
option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1
```

I kept getting error 400 when applying this code. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple reasons why You're getting HTTP 400 status code. One of them could be that Your backend servers really returns that response. Make sure that this is not the case.

Try adding **Host** header after HTTP protocol version as recommended in [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4.2-option%20httpchk).

```
option httpchk <method> <uri> <version>

<method>  is the optional HTTP method used with the requests. When not set,
          the "OPTIONS" method is used, as it generally requires low server
          processing and is easy to filter out from the logs. Any method
          may be used, though it is not recommended to invent non-standard
          ones.

<uri>     is the URI referenced in the HTTP requests. It defaults to " / "
          which is accessible by default on almost any server, but may be
          changed to any other URI. Query strings are permitted.

<version> is the optional HTTP version string. It defaults to "HTTP/1.0"
          but some servers might behave incorrectly in HTTP 1.0, so turning
          it to HTTP/1.1 may sometimes help. Note that the Host field is
          mandatory in HTTP/1.1, and as a trick, it is possible to pass it
          after "\r\n" following the version string.
```

Please note that you have to separate version and each passed header with `\r\n`, also any whitespace characters must be escaped with backslash. Otherwise it will be parsed as next argument to option configuration directive which can lead to erroneous config file.

Example:

```
option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ domain.example.com
```